# Creating a management network with ENIs vs just using security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Looking at AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html?shortFooter=true#scenarios-enis) they lay out a use case for ENIs to create a management network.

So my primary ENI is for public traffic but I create a second ENI for ssh via my private subnet.

But I can just use an ACL to only allow SSH traffic from my company's IP. And if i really want a private VPC I could using a route table for that instead of a second ENI on each instance.

Is there an advantage of 2 ENIs for management network I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have the same result with creating a bastion host. Here's the official quickstart: [link](http://%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/linux-bastion/architecture.html)
You can also attach a security group to the ENI which allows SSH traffic only from a certain subnet.